# How to debug sound volume lowering a 1/2 second after plugging in headphones?

Tags: sound, 19.10, headphones

First, I want to say that `alsamixer` unfortunately doesn't work for my volume issues.

### Problem:

Whenever I plug in headphones to my laptop, the volume starts out "normal" (meaning it sounds how I would expect at my volume level), but then about 1/2 second later the volume drops by about 50%.  If I unplug, then quickly re-plug the headphone jack the same thing happens: normal/loud volume, then a significant drop.

On rare occasions, I can unplug/plug the jack and the volume stays at a constant volume, but this hardly ever happens so it's hard to nail down what is going on.

Also, I can boost the volume above 100%, but then I get clipping.

Neither `alsamixer` nor `pavucontrol` seem to change anything for me, and nothing obvious shows up in those programs when I plug in headphones (meaning, the volume setting stays constant in the UI, but the audible output still drops in my headphones.)

This doesn't happen in Windows, but it happens with multiple headphones in Ubuntu 19.10.

### System info:

Ubuntu 19.10

`5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 05:37:46 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)`

`alsa-info` [command output](https://pastebin.com/8DrxMGa5)

Comment: Did you solve this? Any info on this would be great.

Comment: @ThanasisMattas, unfortunately no. :-(  Since then I've been working on EvilOS™ through WSL because I had some platform code to port.  Does this issue still exist in 22.04?

Comment: I don't know if anyone else experiences it. I certainly do, exactly as you described. I also cannot connect via HDMI to a TV. I don't know if this is related, though. Finally, I use dual boot and both problems are not present on windows, so maybe it is  a drivers issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is what finally helped me:

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/fix_headphones_audio.sh
```

Put the following content into the file

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    DEVICE=`ls /dev/snd/hwC[[:print:]]*D0 | head -n 1`
    if [ ! -z "$DEVICE" ]; then
        hda-verb "$DEVICE" 0x20 SET_COEF_INDEX 0x67
        hda-verb "$DEVICE" 0x20 SET_PROC_COEF 0x3000
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Then create a systemd script

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/fix_headphones_audio.service`

with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fix headphones audio after boot & resume.
After=multi-user.target suspend.target hibernate.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh '/usr/local/bin/fix_headphones_audio.sh'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target suspend.target hibernate.target
```

And then run the following command:

`sudo systemctl enable fix_headphones_audio`

And that's it, no more unwanted sound volume change!
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_Zenbook_UX430/UX530#Headphones_audio_is_too_low